# How to uninstall Android Studio and install it again after errors?

Tags: android

One day I decided to update `build.gradle` plugin in Android Studio, and after that, all my previous projects stopped building and launching on my phone when I test apps. I got these errors:

```
could not perform incremental compilation: could not connect to Kotlin compile daemon, 
Cannot parse result path string: и 
Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource FAILED
```

I tried to fix them by invalidating cache and restarting, and it helped once. But not all projects were fixed. Eventually, I decided to uninstall Android Studio. Initially, I uninstalled it incorrectly, but then I deleted necessary folders and I thought that would fix everything. Unfortunately, my Android Studio still remembers my previous projects, and I can't install the SDK after that.

So, how do I uninstall Android Studio completely and install it again correctly to avoid these errors?

Comment: Reminder that research is expected, so have you seen the existing posts in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid-studio%5D+uninstall Also identify your OS (even what language you are running in) and what you did to "uninstall" (windows settings uninstall, move app directory to trash, ran a command).